# Adobe PSIRT Average Response Time

Tags: incident-response, time

Anyone have any experience in contacting the Adobe Product Security Incident Response Team (PSIRT)? I sent in an exploit that I found two weeks ago and I have not heard from them since. Would they contact me if they don't think that the exploit is worth patching?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR they have an auto-response message, have you received it? They say that it may take some time to respond to reports, but they typically do respond.

If you haven't received their auto-response, there are several options:
- you've got the wrong e-mail (I doubt it though)
- you've received the message, but it was filtered